# Era-Interim NetCDF file using R: wrong time dimension

Tags: r, time, extract, netcdf

I have downloaded data on temperature (t2m) from the ERA-Interim data set as NetCDF file. These data are available for twice a day from 1 January 1979 to 31 July 2016:

```
1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        short t2m[longitude,latitude,time]   
            scale_factor: 0.00208082029268055
            add_offset: 258.514370966807
            _FillValue: -32767
            missing_value: -32767
            units: K
            long_name: 2 metre temperature

     3 dimensions:
        longitude  Size:480
            units: degrees_east
            long_name: longitude
        latitude  Size:241
            units: degrees_north
            long_name: latitude
        time  Size:27454   *** is unlimited ***
            units: hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:0.0
            long_name: time
            calendar: gregorian
```

I have been able to read the longitude and latitude using the ncvar_get code, but when doing this for the time using:

```
t <- ncvar_get(ncin, "time")
length(t) 
27454 # this should be 37.608(years)*365(days)*2(timesperday)
```

I get:

```
head(t)
692508 692520 692532 692544 692556 692568 #hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:0.0

tail(t)
0 0 0 0 0 0 #hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:0.0
```

Then I split the time units string into fields to get them as "d-m-y"

```
tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin, "time", "units")
tustr <- strsplit(tunits$value, " ")
tdstr <- strsplit(unlist(tustr)[3], "-")
tmonth = as.integer(unlist(tdstr)[2])
tday = as.integer(unlist(tdstr)[3])
tyear = as.integer(unlist(tdstr)[1])
chron(t, origin = c(tmonth, tday, tyear))
realtime <- chron(t, origin = c(tmonth, tday, tyear), format = c("d-m-y"))
realtime <- as.character(realtime)

head(realtime)
"09-01-96" "21-01-96" "02-02-96" "14-02-96" "26-02-96" "09-03-96"

tail(realtime)
"01-01-00" "01-01-00" "01-01-00" "01-01-00" "01-01-00" "01-01-00"
```

This does not make sense to me since these data are available from January 1979 to present and both tail(t) and tail(realtime) tell that some of the data refer to 1900-01-01: t is equal to zero 18563 times. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: before starting, have you checked that the dates in the file really match what you think you have?  Try:   cdo showdate file.nc